# How to change album art using Jaudiotagger and MediaScanner in android?

Tags: android, mp3, jaudiotagger

I am using Jaudiotagger 2.2.5 for an android music tagging app. I am able to change metadata like album name, artist name, genre etc. But no matter what I try I can't get the album art part working. I have exhausted all suggestions that I could find online, but nothing seems to work. Jaudiotagger itself lacks documentation nor is the developer very helpful answering such issues.

```
for(Song s : songlist){ //for each song in the album

    File file = new File(artUri);
      if(file.exists()) {

         Artwork cover = ArtworkFactory.createArtworkFromFile(file);
         tag.deleteArtworkField(); 
         tag.createField(cover);
         tag.setField(cover);
         af.commit();
    }



    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(f));
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

Additionally I am using another method to update the mediastore:

```
public void updateAlbumArtMediaStore(Context context, final long id, String art){
    Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart"), id);
    context.getContentResolver().delete(uri,null, null);
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("album_id", id);
    values.put("_data", art);

    Uri newuri = context.getContentResolver()
            .insert(Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart"),
                    values);
    if(newuri!=null){
        Toast.makeText(AlbumTagEditorActivity.this, "UPDATED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        context.getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);

    }else{
        Toast.makeText(AlbumTagEditorActivity.this, "FAILED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

But when I do this it only deletes the cover art.

Its been months since I am trying to get this right. Nothing I have tried ever worked.

Comment: Have you tried `addField` instead of `createField` and `setField`? Let's separate the two things: setting the artwork in the file, and then notifying the Android layer. Can you confirm the artwork is updated in the file first of all? Just run that code, then check the file. Assuming that's working (it should do, WFM), move onto why the `Intent` isn't working.

Comment: Actually the problem is with AudioFileIO.read(file). For some reason this part of te code is not working

Comment: have you found any solution ?

Comment: Yes. Delete cache. That does the trick.

Comment: which cache and how to delete it even I am struggling with the same issue.

Comment: can you answer this question so other people won't suffer?

Comment: @AritraBhattacharyya can you explain how you solved your issue?